# MKMapView - iOS8 MKOverlay - map disappear

Tags: mkmapview, ios8, mkoverlay

I have `MKMapView`. I have added `MKOverlay` on in, rendering it with `MKOverlayRenderer`. When I start application, everything is OK. But if I open some other full screen view and close it, map disappear and turns out gray. I can see the overlay, but no map. If I touch (move) the map, it became visible.

I have tried calling `setNeedsDisplay`, `setRegion`, but none had worked.

If I remove overlays from map, this problem did not appear.

Code for rendering my overlay in overlay renderer.

```
MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);    
CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
```

PS: On iOS7, everything was working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have located error.

In my code, I was changing map type every time, I have refreshing overlays. It was all in one method. Even If I have set same map type as previous one, it did this bug.

Now, I am manually checking, if map has changed its type and only if so, run the code. In case of map change, it blinks but refresh automatically with a new map.

My code:

```
    switch(myAppSettings.mapType)
    {
        case 0:
            if (self.mapView.mapType != MKMapTypeStandard)
                self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            if (self.mapView.mapType != MKMapTypeSatellite)
                self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (self.mapView.mapType != MKMapTypeHybrid)
                self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        default:
            if (self.mapView.mapType != MKMapTypeStandard)
                self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
    }
```

Original, not working version, was without if branches in switch.